# Converting linear regression output in r

Tags: r

My data is a list of two data frames and looks like the following:

```
[[1]]
   Column  strain     N       calc        concentration
1       2  MG         3       1128.727    0.9765625
2       3  MG         3       2577.353    1.9531250
.
.
.

[[2]]
   Column strain    N        calc          concentration
1       2 MG        3        29.14334      0.9765625
2       3 MG        3        65.52667      1.9531250
.
.
.
```

I am running a linear regression on this:

```
linear_regression <- 
     lapply(standardcurve_concentration, 
            lm, 
            formula = calc ~ concentration)
```

Afterward, I wanna get the the coefficient for each linear regression.

I am using the simple task to get the coefficients:

```
linear_regression_sum <- 
  lapply(linear_regression, 
         coef)
```

The output is the following:

```
[[1]]
  (Intercept) concentration 
   12194.0968      703.3598 

[[2]]
  (Intercept) concentration 
     49.20808      30.91862
```

But I would like to have two separate data frames for this linear regression:

```
[[1]]
    Intercept       concentration 
1   12194.0968      703.3598 

[[2]]
     Intercept      concentration 
1     49.20808      30.91862
```

Because I wanna use both coefficients in further calculations.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/drnishaarora_r-learnersworld-data-activity-6888304387421163520-OPQ- might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand this lapply structure with a linear regression but here is some code that maybe points in the right direction.

```
library(broom)


linear_regression_one <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars) 
            
linear_regression_one$coefficients

tidy_linear_regression_one <- tidy(linear_regression_one)

tidy_linear_regression_one_estimate <- tidy_linear_regression_one$estimate


linear_regression_two <- lm(mpg ~ am, mtcars) 
            
linear_regression_two$coefficients

tidy_linear_regression_two <- tidy(linear_regression_two)

tidy_linear_regression_two_estimate <- tidy_linear_regression_two$estimate

regression_estimates <- rbind(tidy_linear_regression_one_estimate, tidy_linear_regression_two_estimate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in single `lapply` call converting the numeric vector from `coef` to a dataframe.

```
result <- lapply(standardcurve_concentration, function(x) {
  as.data.frame(t(coef(lm(calc ~ concentration, x))))
})
```